# jQuery UI sortable connected lists draggable behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When using jQuery UI sortable lists with "connectWith" property and you drag an item from one list into another, it creates a placeholder in the receiver list, BUT it keeps the placeholder also when you move out the item (and when you release the item it goes into the new list). Is there a way to achieve the standard draggable behaviour when moving out, e.g. the connected list should receive the item only if you drag it over the list (and if the item is not over any of the connected lists then the placeholder should go back to the original list where the item comes from)?

HTML:

```
<div class="list list1">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
</div>

<div class="list list2">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.list {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.list > div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

.list1 > div {
  background: green;
}

.list2 > div {
  background: red;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.list').sortable({ connectWith: '.list' });
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ah35waLx/). When you move a green item over the red list, a placeholder is displayed, but when you move the green item out the placeholder is still there in the red list...and should go back to the original green list.